# Sequence does not converge weakly in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $V = c_{0}(\mathbb{N})$, the space of sequences which converge to 0. Then $V^{\ast} \cong \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ and $V^{\ast\ast} = \ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$. Let $a_{n} = (0, 0, \ldots, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1\ldots)$ where $a_{n}$ is the sequence in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ starting with $n - 1$ zeros and remaining terms 1. Why does $a_{n}$ not converge weakly in $V^{\ast\ast}$?

Comment: What do you mean by `converge weakly in `$V^{\ast\ast}$? If I understand this correctly, we will need $V^{\ast\ast\ast}$  for that, by in this case why bother describing $V$ and $V^\ast$?

Comment: was wondering the same :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence converges to $0$ in the weak* topology $\sigma(\ell^\infty,\ell^1)$, since

$$\langle\xi,a_n\rangle = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \xi_k \to 0$$

for all $\xi \in \ell^1$. So if $(a_n)$ converged weakly to $a \in \ell^\infty$, since the weak topology is finer than the weak* topology, we must necessarily have $a = 0$.

But, consider the $\lim$-functional on $c \subset \ell^\infty$, and let $\lambda \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})^\ast$ an extension of that (exists by Hahn-Banach). Then $\lambda(a_n) = 1$ for all $n$, and hence $(a_n)$ does not converge weakly to $0$. Since $0$ was the only possibility for a weak limit, the sequence is not weakly convergent.