# Sequence does not converge weakly in $\ell^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and define $x^k\in\ell^\infty$ by
$$
x_n^k:=\begin{cases}1, & n\leqslant k\\0, & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$

I am searching for a proof that $(x_n^k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ *does not* converge weakly in $\ell^\infty$.

---

I know that there (and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714724/sequence-does-not-converge-weakly-in-ell-infty-mathbbn)) is a similar result (using Banach limits) for the sequence where the first $n$ entries are $0$'s and $1$'s otherwise. But here, its vice versa and I am not sure how to perform the proof.

**Edit**

I wonder, if the following is a valid argument (without referring to the given link at all):

We have $\ell^\infty=(\ell^1)'$ and an isomorphism is given by $T(x)(y)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$ for $x=(x_i)\in\ell^\infty$ and $y=(y_i)\in\ell^1$.

Thus, for the given sequence $(x_n^k)_k$,
$$
T(x_n^k)(y)=\sum_{n=1}^k y_n\to a< \infty~\quad\textrm{as }k\to\infty
$$
for $y=(y_i)\in\ell^1$.

But, as far as I see, $a$ is not unique here, it depends on $y\in\ell^1$, doesn't it?

Thus, $(x_n^k)_k$ cannot converge weakly in $\ell^\infty$ as there is no (unique) limit with respect to weak* topology. In other words, it does not converge in the weak* topology, however, if it converged weakly this would imply weakly* convergence.

Comment: Can't you use the same argument here? The sequence converges pointwise to $(1,1,\ldots)$ so this is the only candidate for the weak limit. However, the Banach limit of every $x^k$ is equal to $0$ but the Banach limit of $(1,1,\ldots)$ is $1$.

Comment: Why is the Banach limit of every $x^k$ equal to $0$? Don't see that

Comment: The limit of every sequence $(1,\ldots, 1, 0,0,\ldots)$ is zero because such a sequence is eventually equal to zero. Since the Banach limit of a sequence is equal to the limit of a sequence when it exists, it follows that the Banach limit of $(1,\ldots, 1, 0,0,\ldots)$ is also zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=(1,1,1,\ldots)$ and let $y^k=y-x^k$. This flips the zeros and ones. Then $(x^k)_k$ is weakly convergent if and only if $(y^k)_k$ is. This will turn your question into the linked question.

Comment: I do not see the following (neither here nor in the link): Suppose $(y^k)_k$ was weakly convergent. Why would the weak limit need to be $y=0$?

Comment: I didn't say that the weak limit would be zero. I said that $(x^k)$ is weakly convergent if and only if $(y^k)$ is. I didn't say they had to converge to the same thing.  

If $(x^k)$ were weakly convergent to some $x$, then $(y^k)$ would be weakly convergent to $y-x$. But $(y^k)$ isn't weakly convergent at all. By contraposition, $(x^k)$ cannot be weakly convergent.

Comment: Then, my problem is that I do not understand the part of the proof given in the link which says that, if the sequence there converged weakly, the weak limit would be $0$.

Comment: For a Banach space $X$, any weakly convergent sequence in $X^*$ must also be weak$^*$ convergent to the same limit in $X^*$. Apply this with $X=\ell^1$. If $(x^k)\subset \ell^\infty$ is weakly convergent to some $x$, then it is also weak$^*$-convergent to the same $x$. But we know it is weak$^*$-convergent to $0$, and weak$^*$-limits are unique, so this forces $x=0$.

Comment: Ok! But why is it weak*-convergent to $0$? I think that's the part I am missing.

Comment: Fix $x=(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\in\ell^1$. Note that since $y^k=(0,\ldots,0,1,1\ldots)$ (with $k$ zeros), $$|y^k(x)| =\Bigl|\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty a_n\Bigr|\leqslant \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty |a_n|,$$ and $\lim_k \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty |a_n|=0$. So $\lim_k |y^k(x)|=0$ for any $x\in \ell^1$.

Comment: I added an idea to my post. My idea is that it cannot be weak convergent since there is no unique limit with respect to weak*-convergence.

Comment: The idea that you've added to your edit does not work. If your idea work, it would also prove that the sequence is not weak$^*$-convergent. But the sequence $(x^k)$ is weak$^*$-convergent to $(1,1,1,\ldots)$.

Comment: A sequence $(x^k)\subset X^*$ is weak$^*$-convergent to $x$ if for any $y\in X$, $\lim_k x^k(y)=x(y)$. This is convergence of numbers, not vectors, and in general, it **does** depend on $y$. So the fact that $\lim_k x^k(y)$ takes different values for different $y$ does not prove that the limit does not exist. 

Uniqueness of limits in the weak$^*$-topology means that $x=\lim_k x^k$ is unique, not that $x(y)=\lim_k x^k(y)$ is the same for all $y$.