# Questions about $a_n$ does not converge weakly in $\ell_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I have some questions about this question and answer:[Sequence does not converge weakly in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714724/sequence-does-not-converge-weakly-in-ell-infty-mathbbn)

> Let $a_{n} = (0, 0, \ldots, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1\ldots)$ where $a_{n}$ is the sequence in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ starting with $n$ zeros and remaining terms 1. Why does $a_{n}$ not converge weakly in $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$?

I can show that $a_0$ converges to $(0,0,0,\dots)$ in weakly-* topology. Because for $x\in \ell^1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty x_k=0
$$

(1) But my question is that why can we say $a_0$ converges to $(0,0,\dots,)$ weakly? I think the correct statement is that "If $x_n$ converges to $x$ weakly, then $x_n$ convergents to $x$ weakly-$*$. Because convergent weakly is stronger than weakly-*.

(2) I do not understand that if we assume that $a_n$ converges to $0$ weakly, why can we get contradiction by the following argument:

> But, consider the $\lim$-functional on $c \subset \ell^\infty$, and let $\lambda \in \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})^\ast$ an extension of that (exists by Hahn-Banach). Then $\lambda(a_n) = 1$ for all $n$, and hence $(a_n)$ does not converge weakly to $0$. Since $0$ was the only possibility for a weak limit, the sequence is not weakly convergent.

Comment: The answer in the link you posted didn't state that $a_n$ converges to 0 weakly - it said that "if" $a_n$ converges to $a$ weakly, then $a$ must be $0$. This is pretty much the same as what you argued in your post.

Comment: @Tri Well, why $a$ must be $0$?

Comment: Because the weak-* topology is weaker than weak topology, thus if $a_n$ converges in $a$ in weak topology, then it converges to $a$ in weak-* topology. But you already proved that $a_n$ converges to $0$ in weak-* topology, so $a=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ converges weakly in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, then $a_n$ converges to $0$ weakly and your argument is perfectly correct.

Now we assume that $a_n$ converges to $0$ weakly in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$, in  order to obtain a contradiction, we need to construct a linear functional $\lambda$ in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)^*$ such that $\lambda(a_n)\not\to0$. We construct this $\lambda$ using the [Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Continuous_extension_theorem). Consider the vector subspace $c\subset\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ defined by
$$c=\left\{x=(x_1, x_2,\cdots)\in\ell^\infty(\mathbb N): \lim_{k\to\infty}x_k\in\mathbb R\right\}.$$
We define a linear functional $f:c\to\mathbb R$ on $c$ by
$$f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k,\qquad \forall x\in c.$$
Then $f$ is a continuous functional on $c$, since clearly $|f(x)|\le \|x\|_{\ell^\infty}$. Now by the [Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Continuous_extension_theorem), there exists a continuous functional $\lambda$ on $\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)$ such that $\lambda(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in c$. For this $\lambda$, we have
$$\lambda(a_n)=f(a_n)=1,\qquad n\in\mathbb N,$$
hence $\lambda(a_n)\not\to0$. This contradicts with the assumption that $a_n$ converges to $0$ weakly.

Comment: But why "if $a_n$ converges weakly, then $a$ must be $0$"?

Comment: @Hermi As you already said in the post, if $a_n$ converges weakly to $a$, then $(a_n)$ converges weakly-* to $a$. Since you already proved that $(a_n)$ converges weakly-* to $0$, and the weak-* limit is unique, we get $a=0$.

Comment: Also, why do we have $f(a_n)=\lim_{k\to\infty} a_n^{(k)}=1$ but not $0$? Sorry, I am a little confused with that $\lim_{n\to\infty} e_n=0$...

Comment: @Hermi If we take $x=a_n=(0, 0, \cdots, 0, 1, 1,\cdots)$, then $x_k=1$ for all $k>n$ hence $f(x)=1$. Note that $a_n$ are elements in $\ell^\infty$, but $x_k$ are components of $x$.